# iOS Safari javascript audio recording

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, audio-recording

As of iOS 12, `MediaRecorder` hasn't been yet implemented. MediaDevices however works, allowing to request access to the user' microphone.

I am trying to figure out if there is at least *one* way of recording audio straight from the browser. I suppose there must be at least one, otherwise what would be the point of granting access to the microphone?

However I can't seem to find a single working solution. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, these two libs are currently the only working solutions for iOS 11.3:

- https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill
- https://github.com/danielstorey/WebAudioTrack

Comment: Both polyfills worked flawlessly not only on ios 11.3 but on 11.x in general. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work on 12.x anymore for Safari. Is there any alternatives for Safari?

Comment: After I wrote this answer, I had the best results with p5-sound; didn't try it with 12.x yet, though.